# Why scrollbar won't show on listbox?

Tags: python, tkinter

I just want put scrollbar to listbox. I try to do it like this ;

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, Label, Frame, Entry, Button, Listbox, 
Scrollbar, END, VERTICAL, RIGHT, Y
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class Page2(tk.Frame):
    
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        
       tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
       ascrollbar = Scrollbar(self, orient=VERTICAL)
       
       diseaseBox = Listbox(self, width=50, height=300, yscrollcommand = ascrollbar.set)
       diseaseBox.grid(row=1, column = 1, padx = 100, pady = 300)
       
       ascrollbar.config(command = diseaseBox.yview)
       ascrollbar.grid(row=1, column=1)
       

       diseaseList = ["one", "two" , "three"]
       
       if diseaseBox is not None:
           for item in diseaseList:
               diseaseBox.insert(END,item)
```

But scrollbar won't show. I try to use pack() method but i am getting this error

> cannot use geometry manager grid inside .!frame.!page2 which already
> has slaves managed by pack

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Your scrollbar and your listbox are in the same place on your grid.

Edit 1 : Adding some code
I think with this lines of codes it's will works

```
diseaseBox = Listbox(self, width=50, height=300, yscrollcommand = ascrollbar.set)
diseaseBox.grid(row=1, column = 1, padx = 100, pady = 300)
       
ascrollbar.config(command = diseaseBox.yview)
ascrollbar.grid(row=1, column=2)
```

Edit 2 :
if is not a problem of grid maybe configure and the making of the scrollbar not good

```
ascrollbar = Scrollbar(self, orient=VERTICAL,command=diseaseBox.yview)
       
diseaseBox = Listbox(self, width=50, height=300)
diseaseBox.grid(row=1, column = 1, padx = 100, pady = 300)
diseaseBox.configure(yscrollcommand = ascrollbar.set)
ascrollbar.grid(row=1, column=0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it didn't change anything.

Comment: how do you import tkinter ?

Comment: I added imports to the question.

Comment: *"But it didn't change anything"*. It does change but you cannot see the change because the listbox is too tall (300 lines, not pixels) so that the scrollbar is put outside the viewable area of the window.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that both the scrollbar and listbox are in the same column. If you put the scrollbar in some other column it will show up.

However, you also have the problem that a) the listbox is more than twice the height of the window, and b) the scrollbar is not being stretched vertically to fill the column. So, the scrollbar is centered vertically in the column and thus is off the edge of the window.

If you add `sticky='ns'` when calling `grid` on the scrollbar, it will show up. It would also show up if you made the listbox much smaller and with less padding.